# Installing R and RStudio on Chromebook Samsung 3

Tags: r, linux, rstudio, chromebook, crouton

I have been trying to but struggling to install R and RStudio on my Chromebook Samsung 3. I have it set-up with Crouton with XFCE/Xiwi and use Trusty. I can install R just fine but either can't install Rstudio at all or can get the icon for Rstudio to show up but nothing happens when I click on it. Can someone give me a process on how to install these effectively on my device?

Comment: This is not a question?

Comment: The question and answer seem to be about _"how do I install software on a Linux operating system"_.  This should be on a Linux user Q&A site, not a programming Q&A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## UPDATE 2020:

I am no longer using Crouton, but rather the built in Linux option (Crostini). In the Linux terminal, I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade; sudo apt-get update --fix-missing; sudo apt autoclean; sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt install -y gnupg2

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 'E19F5F87128899B192B1A2C2AD5F960A256A04AF'

sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add this line. Can use a different mirror if desired. (Note: older versions of Crostini were running Stretch by default instead of Buster)

```
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian buster-cran35/
```

Then back in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install xclip

sudo apt install -y r-base r-base-dev

sudo apt-get install gdebi-core

sudo apt install -y libgstreamer1.0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0 libxslt-dev libnss3

sudo apt --fix-broken install

sudo curl -o rstudio.deb https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-1.2.5033-amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i rstudio.deb

sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade; sudo apt --fix-broken install; sudo apt-get update --fix-missing; sudo apt autoclean; sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get autoremove
```

---

## ORIGINAL ANSWER:

It admittedly took me a long time, but I was finally able to install R and RStudio on my Chromebook Samsung 3. I have it set-up with Crouton with XFCE/Xiwi and use Trusty. After setting up Crouton, etc. here is what I had to do in the Linux terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-get install selinux-policy-default
sudo apt-get install libqpol1
```

Add these lines:

```
deb https://<FOO>/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
deb https://<FOO>/ trusty-backports main restricted universe
```

to file

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

(replace FOO with the CRAN mirror of your choice and replace trusty if applicable)

Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rrutter
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt upgrade r-base r-base-dev
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
wget https://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-1.1.442-amd64.deb
sudo gdebi rstudio-server-1.1.442-amd64.deb
wget https://download1.rstudio.org/rstudio-0.99.896-amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev
sudo gdebi rstudio-0.99.896-amd64.deb
cd /usr/bin/
rstudio
```

- [source](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html)
- [source](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/)
- [source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771314/install-rstudio-rstudio-server-already-exists)
- [source](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206330288-Can-t-install-latest-version-of-Rstudio)

Comment: Just trying this with a colleague - I bellieve we needed an extra install before `rstudio`, of `sudo apt install -y libclang-dev`.  Also the less-experienced might prefer `nano` to edit the sources file: `apt get install -y nano; sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`.