# difficulty installing RStudio on Chromebook

Tags: r, chromebook

I am new to R, but need to work with it for my dissertation.

I have managed to download it onto my Acer Chromebook 311 using this guidance
[here](https://levente.littvay.hu/chromebook/)

That worked all fine and without any issues, until I tried to install RStudio.

I downloaded the Rstudio file from here
[text](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download)
and chose the Debian/Ubuntu version as per instructions.

But I was unable to successfully install the file on my Chromebook

Using this command and file
sudo apt-get install ./rstudio-2023.06.1-524-amd64.deb

I tried to install the downloaded file, but it didn't work and I got the following error message:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'rstudio:amd64' instead of './rstudio-2023.06.1-524-amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
rstudio:amd64 : Depends: libssl1.0.0:amd64 but it is not installable or
libssl1.0.2:amd64 but it is not installable or
libssl1.1:amd64 but it is not installable
Depends: libclang-dev:amd64 but it is not installable
Depends: libxkbcommon-x11-0:amd64 but it is not installable
Depends: libsqlite3-0:amd64 but it is not installable
Depends: libpq5:amd64 but it is not installable
Depends: libc6:amd64 (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I tried this suggestion from here:
[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49620951/installing-r-and-rstudio-on-chromebook-samsung-3)
Just trying this with a colleague - I believe we needed an extra install before rstudio, of sudo apt install -y libclang-dev

But that didn't solve the problem either.

I have also searched on google for solutions and tried various suggestions, different download versions of the file and fixes, but unfortunately none of it worked and I am unable to get RStudio installed on my laptop. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I suspect since you're going through the trouble of this installation that you don't want to use RStudio Cloud - now [Posit Cloud](https://posit.cloud).  In case it hadn't come up, I thought it might be worth flagging.

Comment: Thanks, Dave, I just followed what my uni module told me to do and that said use Rstudio. I didn't realise that there was a cloud version. I will check that out since I am having all this trouble getting RStudio installed, thank you

Comment: Is your CPU ARM? If so, you need to use a package for ARM.

Comment: Thanks Norio, I checked and it seems that it has an ARM Octa-Core processor.  Do you mean that I need a different version of the RStudio or is the package for ARM something different altogether?

Comment: Does this help?
https://dailies.rstudio.com/rstudio/cherry-blossom/electron/jammy-arm64/

Comment: I went to that site and downloaded and installed RStudio, and it worked. Thank you all so much for your help, this is brilliant.